# can anyone explain the meaning of this peace of code from c

Tags: c

the code is from C the code is written below:-

```
int main(){
    char* time = (char *)malloc(10240 * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s",time);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: We are not a "explain some code I found on the internet or given by a friend who is not willing to explain" site.

Comment: There's many problems with this code -- `sizeof(char)` is redundant, one shouldn't cast the result of `malloc`, the memory is never freed, the return code from `scanf` isn't checked, the code is vulnerable to a buffer overflow, you're missing includes for stdio.h and stdlib.h. The code doesn't have any meaning -- it reads input and then exits.

Answer (score 1):

Error:

Because there is no prototype in scope for `malloc` the compiler interprets the result (of type `void*`) as type `int`.

Then it converts that value to type `char*` and assigns the resulting (meaningless) value to `time`.

Then, still using the meaningless value, it attempts to store there a value read and interpreted as an integer from standard input.

It then exits without doing anything more. Particularly it doesn't use the value read or release the memory (probably) allocated earlier.

Answer (score 0):

it has first reserved memory dynamically from the heap by using malloc function, then it is scanning a string. pay attention to the format fo %s conversion specifier: the argument related to it is a pointer.(not for example time[0].)

don't forget that the memory should be free after the work is done

```
syntax: free (time);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char* time = (char *)malloc(10240 * sizeof(char));
```

Here, you use `malloc()` to allocate `10240 * sizeof(char)` blocks of memory for you. `sizeof(char)` is equal to 4 bytes, so you are allocated `10240 * 4 = 40960` blocks of memory as `int` by default, as you have not specified any prototype in scope (seen as `void*`) for `malloc()`

You then cast the memory space to a `char *` and have `*time` point the first block in that memory allocated to you.

```
scanf("%s",time);
```

In this line, you try to store a value read as integer input from `scanf()` in `time`. Your format specifier is wrong here.

The program then terminates, without freeing the memory you allotted in it, and without doing anything with the inout you took with `scanf()`.